# format text input in currency pattern using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have text input which when entered in formats it in currency pattern like **1,000,500**. The problem right now is that a user can enter numbers like `000.00, 0,0000,000, 000,438,339`.

I want to find out if someone can help me with a regex that removes the starting zeros except it is in this format `0.00`.

If I entered more than one zero without placing the decimal point after the first zero e.g `00` or `0000` then it should return `0.` So :

```
000.00 should be 0.00
0,0000,000 should be 0
000,438,339 should be 438,339
```

I was doing this `'0000.00'.replace(/^(00*)(.*)$/, '$2')` but *id* doesn't cover all the edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `/^0+(\d+(\.\d{1,2})?)$/` after removing commas from the string; This covers the three cases you've listed:

```
'0,0000,000'.replace(/,/g, "").replace(/^0+(\d+(\.\d{1,2})?)$/, '$1')
// '0'

'000.00'.replace(/,/g, "").replace(/^0+(\d+(\.\d{1,2})?)$/, '$1')
// '0.00'

'000,438,339'.replace(/,/g, "").replace(/^0+(\d+(\.\d{1,2})?)$/, '$1')
// '438339'
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the following code.The general idea is to check first if there is a dot notation in the input value. Then split the value at  dot position.Via if condition i check if the first portion of the number (00. or 000. or 10.) is divided with number 1 and then the result is not equal to 0.This ensure that the integer portion is not zero's.After this if conditional I reform the value using toLocaleString() method for the first portion of the initial input number and reset the input value:

```js
$('#myButton').on('click',function(){
  var currency=$('#myInput').val();
  var search=currency.indexOf(".");
  if(search){
    currency=currency.split(".");
    if((currency[0]/1)==0){
      currency[0]="0";     
     var newNum=currency[1].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
      $('#myInput').val(currency[0]+"."+newNum);
    }else{
      var newNum=currency[1].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
      $('#myInput').val(Math.round(parseInt(currency[0]))+"."+newNum);
    }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="myInput" />
  <button id="myButton">Get Currency</button>
```

Comment: We're not using jQuery any more, especially if the OP has not tagged his question `jQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

The commented snippet below illustrates effectively what you want to achieve; the function formats your given value to the desired format.

```js
// Defining input cases variable.
var caseOne = '000.00';
var caseTwo = '00,0000,000';
var caseThree = '000,438,339';

// Assigning a given case to the someAmount variable (any of the cases above).
// For the purpose of this illustration, we assigned caseThree as value to someAmount.
var someAmount = caseThree;

// formatInput function (to format the given input case).
function formatInput(amountToFormat) {
    if (amountToFormat.match(/^0*(\.)(0*)$/)) {
        console.log('0'.concat(amountToFormat.replace(/^0*(\.)(0*)$/, '$1' + '$2')));
    }
    if (amountToFormat.match(/^0*(\,)([0-9]+)(\,)([0-9]+)$/)) {
        var blockTwo = amountToFormat.replace(/^0*(\,)(0*)(\,)(0*)$/, '$2');
        var blockFour = amountToFormat.replace(/^0*(\,)(0*)(\,)(0*)$/, '$4');
        if (eval(blockTwo) != 0 && eval(blockFour) != 0) {
            console.log(amountToFormat.replace(/^0*(\,)([0-9]+)(\,)([0-9]+)$/, '$2' + '$3' + '$4'));
        } else {
            console.log('0');
        }
    }
}

// Use the formatInput function where needed by passing in the value
// of the input to be formatted as someAmount.
// Expected outputs:
// 0.00 for caseOne, 0 for caseTwo, and 438,339 for caseThree.

formatInput(someAmount);
// Expected output for the purpose of this illustration: 438,339
```